# angular create form in Service class(typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create form angular form that is accessible by 4 components. I was thinking is there any way I can create form in the service layer and all the components can access that form (like an interface) but
**formGroup]=serviceObject.form**
is not working .

**Use case**: All form components are tabs on the homepage, each tab has some part of the form.

I have search lot but i didn't find anything

Comment: what exactly is not working? it should

Comment: Ya, I tried ones again, it works with initializing form with a constructor, previously I was trying with the implementing onInit. but it was giving an error Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance